# How can I optimise my trigger for bulk insert scenario?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sql-tuning

I have created a trigger which updates a column in a table (say colX) based on value in another column (colY). The colY can be inserted or updated and if colX is empty it should be set with the value of colY. The problem is I have a file upload which inserts a bulk of record in this table with colY filled. Most of the times the colX is also filled but if its not filled in I expect this trigger to do it for me. This is my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_FILLCOLY
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TAB1
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    
BEGIN
if (:new.COLX is not null and :new.COLY is null) then 
:new.COLY:= :new.COLX;
end if;

if (:new.COLA is not null and :new.COLBis null) then 
:new.COLB := :new.COLA;
end if;

END;
/
```

Is there any way I can make this trigger faster? Right now the upload is taking twice the time it takes without the trigger in place.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't think a faster case would be provided, since there's no DML, and so no cost for this current operation. Btw, Do you really think such a design, since holding a column which already can be computed from the other columns ,mostly has no sense.

Comment: I am not sure but try the `when` clause and put both of your condition in OR and check with the same trigger.

Comment: Hi @BarbarosÖzhan I agree, this is not an optimal approach. I am working with a system already in production and doesn't have lot of choices. The other option, which we do currently is running an update query after the upload and its quite fast. The only downside is its manual and we have a risk of forgetting to run the script. A trigger would avoid that.

Comment: The trigger is essentially doing row-by-row operations, where the update you were previously performing is a bulk operation. My best guess is that the trigger will always be significantly slower, just because of that basic difference.

Comment: Thank you for your response @pmdba, I suspected as much. I was hoping if there is something I can do which would make the trigger execute once all rows are updated. I know this is not a right candidate for statement level trigger but maybe there was something else of that sort.

Comment: @Tejash unfortunately that didn't result in a better performance.

Comment: I would echo others in urging you to forget the trigger.  It's obvious that if B is null, it's value is always derived from A.  It costs almost nothing to make this determination when the column is selected, using an nvl function. One fundamental rule of data design is 'never store that which can be calculated at run time'.

Comment: You say you have an update process that gives(?) satisfactory performance, but it is manual and you worry about not running it. Then you could put that process in an After Statement trigger. That way you cannot forget and it runs only once for the upload (or what ever commit interval you have). Still, NOT storing derivable data is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You might try leaving colx and coly alone (no trigger) and defining a third virtual column which displays the result of your null logic.  That should drop your load time back to what is was but at the cost of that logic having to be executed at query time.  You could also try disabling the trigger, doing the load, update the table with your null logic, then enabling the trigger.  That might run a bit faster.

Comment: I don't understand the part of dropping/disabling the trigger. That would mean the purpose is not solved right? I still need the functionality where colY is populated, either via this trigger or some other means. We currently use a update script which we need to execute manually and I am trying to avoid that, because we might forget to do that.

Answer (score 0):

How often do you load this bulk file? If this is a one-off exercise - or a regularly scheduled job which is run through a procedure - here is an alternate approach.

1. Disable the trigger
2. Upload the bulk file
3. Use set-based UPDATE statements to apply the business rules to the uploaded records
4. Re-enable the trigger

The set-based operation should be faster than the row-by-row firing of the trigger. However, you may need to tune that statement to get satisfactory performance. How much work you put in might depend on how often you run this process.

Comment: We already do this. The upload happens quite often, and manually triggered as and when we receive a file from external system. The only reason we look at triggers is to avoid forgetting to run the update statement.

Comment: If this is something you do regularly then you should script it. Code does not "forget" to do something.